# How to install Xamarin for Visual Studio 2015 when Visual Studio 2013 is installed too?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I install both Visual Studio 2013 and 2015. I need install Xamarin for VS 2015. But I can't do it because by default it's installing for VS 2013.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the link below may assist you:

> first, uninstall everything related to xamarin.
>
> second, open vs2015 and create new andriod project
>
> third, when project is created you'll see instructions to downloading xamarin.
> Download the xamarin installer for vs2015, install it, after installation - open vs2015 and see the newly added projects.

http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/blagunas/archive/2014/11/14/installing-xamarin-for-visual-studio-2015-preview-side-by-side-with-visual-studio-2013.aspx

Comment: I'll add the relevant info from the link. Thanks for your feedback.