# Xamarin Installer: How to install Xamarin in vs2013 when vs2015 is also installed

Tags: xamarin

I downloaded the Xamarin for windows installer. It installed Xamarin no problems, but only in VS2015.
On  Xamarin.com install videos they show Xamarin installer working in VS2013.

Uninstall everything first, is not an option. 
[How to install Xamarin for Visual Studio 2015 when Visual Studio 2013 is installed too?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30913859/how-to-install-xamarin-for-visual-studio-2015-when-visual-studio-2013-is-install)

Surely there is a better way to install Xamarin in both VS2013 vs2015.
Due to existing c# projects and release levels i need both vs2013 and vs2015.

It sees Vs2015 and installs there. No aoption to add to VS2013 ?
Any ideas how to install Xamarin in both versions ?

[image]

Comment: Try our troubleshooting guide here: https://kb.xamarin.com/customer/en/portal/articles/1643349-missing-visual-studio-extensions-after-installation

Answer (score 0):

- Go to Programs and Features
- Select Xamarin and click change In the proceeding screen click on change you will the screen as below.
- If you see a cross change it to install to show a disk icon as highlighted below.
- And then follow the
  steps ahead.

I had the same problem, but mine was the other way I had it installed in VS2013 and I wanted to install in VS2015. This is what I did. Probably this might help you.

[image]

Comment: The Xamarin Installer i have doesnt offer this. It goes straight to installing in vs2015 community edition.  I added a screen shot to Question

Comment: You will still find Xamarin in your Programs and Features.